# A manhwa (or manga) where the main antagonist is the protagonist's future self

Tags: threads-of-time

It's been bugging me for a few days now. I can't really remember a lot about it, but here are the things I kind of remember:

- I think it was Korean manhwa
- The setting was old, martial arts was common.
- I think the MC had amnesia.
- He liked to climb trees (shown chapter 1, I think)
- He time traveled back to a younger body (mind traveled)
- His parents were suspicious of him for being "different than usual".
- His parents were killed by thugs.
- The female helper who was taking care of the main character got kidnapped and raped.
- He later tracked the guy who attacked them and was about to kill him, when suddenly a girl stopped him from doing so. It turned out to be the helper; she was pregnant and in love with her captor. He left through the window.
- The main character was scared of the main enemy (I think >.<)
- The enemy was wearing Sephiroth-like trench coat (tall)
- Near the end, he found out that the enemy was him from the future (or alternate outcome of his choices)
- They fought in the courtyard and both died I think, or just his future self.

I'm not sure if this is only 1 manga that I'm describing. It kinda feels 2.

I have tried googling this with what I think the genre/tags it would be under, but failed to find it :(

I hope someone can help me stop this nagging in my head >.<  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4):

It's probably [**Threads of Time**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threads_of_Time), a Korean manhwa.

It has been a few years since I read it, so my memory is fuzzy about the fine details, but it has enough similarities to be a match.

I definitely remember these details you wrote in the question:

> - It was Korean manhwa
> - Martial arts was common.
> - He time traveled back to a younger body.
> - His parents were suspicious of him for being "different than usual".
> - The female helper who was taking care of the main character got kidnapped and raped.
> - He later tracked the guy who attacked them and was about to kill him, when suddenly a girl stopped him from doing so. It turned out to be the helper; she was pregnant and in love with her captor. He left through the window
> - The main character was scared of the main enemy.

The last 2 details (reproduced below) might be from a different manga if you're completely certain about it.

> - Near the end, he found out that the enemy was him from the future (or alternate outcome of his choices)
> - They fought in the courtyard and both died I think, or just his future self.

However, I think you might have gotten those details wrong, since the MC time traveled back into the brother of one of the villain's victim in order to untangle or sever the Threads of Time (Fate?). Near the end, he realized that the villain was his past self and he defeated him, but he also died soon after and returned to his present time. Though this time around, he is no longer tied down by fate/destiny because he broke the cycle.

Source: Years of reading manga.

Anyway, I hope this is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of them sounds a lot like "Rikudo".

Riku experienced a lot of pain and tragedy in his early life. After his father's death, a former-boxer Yakuza man taught him how to do a basic punch, and that punch saved his life when he had to defend himself from his mom's drug dealer. He ended up taking the drug dealer's life, marking him as a killer. Criminals continued to come after him, leading to more tragedy for the people who attempted to care for him. All of this drove him to ask that same former boxer to teach him to become stronger, which led him to a rundown gym, his door to the world of pro boxing!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very sure about this, I saw this a long time ago so just as the memory of it is somewhat vague in your mind it is also vague in mine, but your description is reminding me about [Flame of Recca](http://myanimelist.net/anime/238/Rekka_no_Honoo).

It doesn't match your description exactly but seeing how you're not sure you're describing a single series I thought this might be one of them.